# Trouble getting tesseract to work on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tesseract

Sorry if this was already asked and I'm just blind.

I recently got a Raspberry Pi, and I am trying to get it to run a discord bot that uses Tesseract-OCR.

I currently have tesseract installed in "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe", which is not visible when navigating through file manager but appeared as an option when running the installer (ran [this](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0.20211201.exe) installer using wine).

Instead of troubleshooting all the files, I made a test file of sorts, containing this:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd="C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe
text = pytesseract.image_to_string("\\home\\boi\\Downloads\\Lyceum-of-Wisdom-Rise-of-Kingdoms-2.jpg")
print(text)
```

Image found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=peerless+scholar+question+rok&sca_esv=585338254&rlz=1C1FHFK_en-GBAU991AU991&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AM9HkKmbh4wGnzE0BmnMyfyGGxp6-Evibw:1700965328104&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZrqDRzeCCAxWbhq8BHVpODxcQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1280&bih=642&dpr=1.5#imgrc=cRoVeHI-9cfimM)

When I run it it spits out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boi/Downloads/RoK-discord-bots-main/t.py", line 4, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string('\\home\\boi\\Downloads\\Lyceum-of-Wisdom-Rise-of-Kingdoms-2.jpg')
  File "/home/boi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/home/boi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/home/boi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/boi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

This is because of the where it is installed or the PATH settings, but I am too chicken to try and change the PATH as this is my first time doing so with Linux. I have tried to re-install Tesseract like [this](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-tesseract-ubuntu/) but it did not work.

Would be open to any help or guidance :)

Comment: On a Linux machine there is no path C:/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract has prebuilt binaries for Debian (what the Raspberry Pi OS is based on) that you can install on your Raspberry Pi. You don't need to use the windows binaries, so installing through Wine is unnecessary.

Check out https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html to find the installation instructions for the prebuilt binaries.

It looks like the actual installation instructions are kind of hard to navigate to, but you can find them at https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/html/. To install the latest stable version, you'll want to do step 2.2 from that guide, and ignore 2.1 and 2.3

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot find a direct download from there and don't know which packages I need. Once i get to this page: https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/packages5/ what do I do?

Comment: I've updated my post to be more clear, I didn't realize they didn't link directly to the instructions page from their installation guide.

Comment: Once I have ran that, how do I connect it to a python file? 
 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd="???"

Comment: After the installation command is run, tesseract will be in your `PATH`, so you shouldn't need the  `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd="..."` line. It should work without that.

Comment: Still not working sorry